# PYTHON: Find index of the largest number in a list without built-in functions and list modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Write a function, max index, that takes a list as a parameter and returns the index of the largest number in the list.
When writing the function, you are given the following rules:

- You are not allowed to use the max function
- You are not allowed to use any list methods
- You must use a Pythonic FOR loop. This means you CANNOT use the range function or enumerate function in your loop
- If the largest number appears more than once, you should return the smallest index

This is so wrong because it fails to loop through the list and I also don't know how to compare the two indexes in case the largest value appears more than once in the list.

```
def max_index(lon):
  """
  input is a list of numbers.
  returns the index of the largest number in the list
  """
  max = lon[0]
  index = 0 
  for n in lon:
    if n>max:
      max = n
    index+=1
  return index
```

Comment: What's "not pythonic" about range??? (which is [a class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-range) btw)

Comment: "in case the largest value appears more than once in the list" there shouldn't be a problem because `n>max` is not going to be True (since it implies _strictly greater than_, not _greater or equal_).

Comment: The easiest solution using your code the way it is, would be just to store the index whenever `n>max`, not only the max value.

Comment: "it fails to loop through the list"... nope, it does iterate perfectly, it's just returning the size of the list because it iterates until the end and updates the index in each iteration, independently of whether the value is maximum or not (and adds 1 after reaching the last item, so you get the length instead of the index of the last item).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. If this is a homework question, you wont learn without trying, so try out different solutions starting with the for loop. Good luck!

```
def max_index(lon):
    max_val=0
    counter=0
    max_index=0
    for num in lon:
        if num > max_val:
            max_val = num
            max_index = counter
        counter = counter + 1
    return max_index
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most effecient approach, but I'm pretty sure this would work:

```
def max_index(lon):
    current_index = 0
    largest_index = 0
    max = 0
    for item in lon:
        if item > max:
            max = item
            largest_index = current_index
        current_index += 1
    return largest_index
```